# Mostrar div si los datos guardados en el localstorage son correctos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un tipo de **login** pero necesito mostrar un div que lleva información si los datos ingresados o 'recordardos' son correctos, en el formulario **login** claro.

por ahora solo tengo el script que guarda los datos ingresados en el formulario **register** qué más le agrego para alcanzar lo que busco?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#register').click(function(){        
              
        var ema = document.getElementById("email-register").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password-register").value;
        
        localStorage.setItem("Email", ema);
        localStorage.setItem("Password", pass);
    });   
});
```

```css
#login-real{
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 20px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #ff0;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
#login-real > h2{
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="register">
<h2>Register</h2>

<input id="email-register" type="email" placeholder="Ingresar correo" required>

<input id="password-register" type="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" required>

<button id="register">Registrar</button>

</form>

<form class="login">

<h2>Login</h2>

<input id="email-login" type="email" placeholder="Ingresar correo" required>

<input id="password-login" type="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" required>

<button id=""login>Iniciar</button>

</form>


<div id="login-real">
<h2>Inicio exitoso</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: qué es lo que define la "correctitud" de los datos guardados?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recuperar los valores de `localstorage` mediante : `localStorage.getItem('Email')`

- Creas un función dentro del evento on click '#login' el botón que ejecuta la acción
- La función recoge los valores de los inputs y los almacena en una variable.
- Cambias el display del '#login-real'
- mediante un IF compruebas que sean iguales los datos almacenados con los introducidos en el input.
- Dependiendo de cada caso cambias el color de fondo y el texto.

**Función para detectar el login:**

```
 $('#login').on('click',function(){

      var login_email = $('#email-login').val();
      var login_password = $('#password-login').val()
      $('#login-real').css('display','block');

      if( login_email == localStorage.getItem('Email') &&  login_password == localStorage.getItem('Password')) {
          $('#login-real').css('background','green');
          $('#login-real').html('Login realizado con éxito.');
        } else {
          $('#login-real').css('background','red');
          $('#login-real').html('Se ha producido un fallo en el login.');
        }

    });
```

**Ejemplo completo:**
*Testado*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register').click(function(){

        var ema = document.getElementById("email-register").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password-register").value;

        localStorage.setItem("Email", ema);
        localStorage.setItem("Password", pass);
    });

    $('#login').on('click',function(){

      var login_email = $('#email-login').val();
      var login_password = $('#password-login').val()
      $('#login-real').css('display','block');

      if( login_email == localStorage.getItem('Email') &&  login_password == localStorage.getItem('Password')) {
          $('#login-real').css('background','green');
          $('#login-real').html('Login realizado con éxito.');
        } else {
          $('#login-real').css('background','red');
          $('#login-real').html('Se ha producido un fallo en el login.');
        }

    });


});

</script>
<style>
#login-real{
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 20px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #ff0;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
#login-real > h2{
margin: 0;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="register">
<h2>Register</h2>

<input id="email-register" type="email" placeholder="Ingresar correo" required>

<input id="password-register" type="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" required>

<button id="register">Registrar</button>

</form>



<h2>Login</h2>

<input id="email-login" type="email" placeholder="Ingresar correo" required>

<input id="password-login" type="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" required>

<button id="login">Login</button>



<div id="login-real">
<h2>Inicio exitoso</h2>
</div>
```

Si necesitas que se creen funcionalidades en el servidor lo mejor es hacerlo con AJAX, para poder operar en el lado del servidor.

---

## Ejemplo con AJAX

El procedimiento es casi el mismo lo único que el if lo colocamos en otro archivo .php, con esto podrás realizar consultas a BBDD o cualquier otra funcionalidad que necesites.

Archivo con php llamado **ajax.php**

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['login_email'];
$login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

$localstorage_email = $_POST['local_mail'];
$localstorage_pass = $_POST['local_pass'];

if($email == $localstorage_email
&& $login_password == $localstorage_pass){
  // realizas tus operaciones con el servidor

  echo "<div style='background-color: green;'>Login realizado con éxito (Desde AJAX)</div>";
} else {
  echo "<div style='background-color: red;'>Login Incorrecto (Desde AJAX)</div>";
}
die();
 ?>
```

El archivo **index** con el ajax. veras que a diferencia del anterior esta vez el on click llama  al archivo **ajax.php** mediante la funcion de `$.ajax`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#register').click(function(){

        var ema = document.getElementById("email-register").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password-register").value;

        localStorage.setItem("Email", ema);
        localStorage.setItem("Password", pass);
    });

    $('#login').on('click',function(){

      var login_email = $('#email-login').val();
      var login_password = $('#password-login').val()

      $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { login_email: login_email,
              login_password: login_password,
            local_mail : localStorage.getItem('Email'),
            local_pass:localStorage.getItem('Password') }
          })
            .done(function( msg ) {
              $('#login-real').css('display','block');
              $('#login-real').html(msg);
            });


    });


});

</script>
<style>
#login-real{
margin-top: 20px;
padding: 20px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #ff0;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
#login-real > h2{
margin: 0;
}
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="register">
<h2>Register</h2>

<input id="email-register" type="email" placeholder="Ingresar correo" required>

<input id="password-register" type="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" required>

<button id="register">Registrar</button>

</form>



<h2>Login</h2>

<input id="email-login" type="email" placeholder="Ingresar correo" required>

<input id="password-login" type="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña" required>

<button id="login">Login</button>



<div id="login-real">
<h2>Inicio exitoso</h2>
</div>
```

> Cuidado en tu código el id del botón del login no está puesto correctamente...
>
> Debería estar así :  `<button id="login">Iniciar</button>` ya que en el tuyo esta
>   fuera de las comillas.